# I cant solve this error in xcode5.0.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_testbluetooth", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Make sure your `testbluetooth.m` is included in your target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Xcode (more precisely in your case, Clang compiler) complains about a symbol not found for an architecture, it's probably because you've forgot to add reference to a framework you are not aware of! for example if you are using a 3rd party framework, first thing you should check, is the dependencies it has on other frameworks, in your case, probably **CoreBluetooth.framework**.

Open your project, select your target, in the build phase, open ***Link Binaries with libraries*** and select the frameworks your need to add reference to.
good luck

Comment: It's not likely that this is a framework issue. I don't think `CoreBluetooth` defines a class named `testbluetooth`.

Comment: @rmaddy, CoreBluetooth framework is a mere speculation. In my experience it's 99% a framework missing. some 3rd party frameworks or projects forget to mention their dependencies. and when one tries to compile the project, symbol not found errors happen because they need to be added to the final target they are getting compiled in.

Comment: Right, see my comment below the question.

Comment: you maybe right, but target membership is never a solution for .m files but .h files, .m files must be added to ***compile Sources*** part of target.

Comment: @M.Porooshani Those two things are the same in the end.  Target membership means it will be put into that target's compile sources.